# flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated returns False if not in Blueprint route

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-socketio

With Flask-SocketIO, I want to send data from the current user to the Message event on the client-side.  The problem is, the current_user object returns an Anonymous user unless I access it inside a route handler.

Here is __init__.py (to show imports):

```
from flask import Blueprint

chat = Blueprint('chat', __name__)

from . import routes, events
```

Here is routes.py:

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from . import chat


@chat.route('/chatroom', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def chatroom():
  print(f"\ninside route: {current_user.is_authenticated}\n") # returns true
  if request.method == 'POST':
    return redirect(url_for('chat.chatroom'))
  return render_template('chatroom.html')
```

Here is events.py:

```
from flask_login import current_user
from flask_socketio import emit
from ..extensions import socketio


@socketio.on('message', namespace='/chatroom')
def handle_message(in_data):
    print(f"\ninside event: {current_user.is_authenticated}\n") # returns false
    sender_name = 'Seth'
    sender_pic_id = ''
    out_data = {
        'msg': f"{sender_name}: {in_data['msg']}",
        'pic_id': sender_pic_id
    }
    emit('message', out_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not 'blueprint vs. not' that's significant here, it's 'socket i/o or not'. Sessions don't automatically migrate from one to the other.

See https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-socketio-and-the-user-session for a lengthier discussion.

Comment: So the session from the HTTP GET request (for /chatroom) is copied and forked over to the SocketIO session? I still don't understand why current_user returns anonymous. Also, I tried using Flask-Session like he suggested, but I think the extension is dead and/or discontinued because the import doesn't work.